# A div element will be visible if its textboxs are filled with their respective value from database in html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How can I make a div visible, only when its textboxes are filled with their respective value which are stored in a database?

Comment: For empty contents you can use like `p:empty{ display:none;}` but you are not clear exactly what you are trying and also no codes shared which you are referring.

Answer (score 1):

### with CSS

div:empty{ display:none;}

### With JS

You can check the value of textboxes if they are empty or not and accordingly add classes to the div/p element
EX :

```
if (document.getElementByID("#textBox1").value === '') {
 //then add classes to div accordingly 
}
```